# Google domains not working DNS issue

Tags: google-chrome, dns

When accessing Google products (google.com / youtube.com etc...) I often get a :

```
Oops! Google Chrome could not connect to google.com
Try reloading: google.­com
Additional suggestions:
Access a cached copy of google.­com
Search on Google:
```

error on Chrome. This happens on all my browsers, and all my devices that are connected to my router.

It seems to be a DNS issue with my router and specifically Google. What is this problem, and how can it be solved? It's been like this for about 2 weeks now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to test if it's a DNS issue is to try using Google's public DNS servers -

```
 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4
```

Instead of the ones you are currently using.

You may also have some sort of malware or virus issue.

Comment: Would adding Google's public DNS server affect anything else? What could be the cause of this? I doubt it's a malware issue because several devices (including iOS). I run a Mac that I regularly scan and has no issues.

Comment: adding googles dns won't affect anything else other than to speed it up.  Its provided by google but its just a public DNS server.

Comment: Some DNS servers "hijack" (or "proxy" if you prefer) DNS requests to Google (OpenDNS does, or did at one time) so by using Google's DNS servers you are sure to get proper DNS resolution for Google sites unless you ISP is hijacking port 53 requests.